# Available in iOS 8.0 and later - build for iOS 7

Tags: ios, ios8

I am using `traitCollectionDidChange` for iOS 8 with is fine. The documentation says [Available in iOS 8.0 and later](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITraitEnvironment_Ref/) But I am able to build - and also the method is called even when I build(build settings / iOS deployment target) for iOS 7.

Does that mean that the iOS sdk is able to build traitCollectionDidChange for iOS 7?

```
- (void) traitCollectionDidChange:(UITraitCollection *)previousTraitCollection{
    [super traitCollectionDidChange:previousTraitCollection];
}
```

Maybe it has to do with "Levels" with I need to clear out:[image]

Comment: It can build with any methods that are in the sdk version you are building with, which is usually the most recent one.  If you tried to call that method on iOS 7 it would crash though.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it is impossible, compilator will tell you that your deployment target is to low.

I have tested it on my own, below you can see results:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hmm, strange - I get no error. I am running Xcode 7.3.1

Comment: Because you're using objective-c and he's using swift

Comment: @dan you have right, objc don't handle availability as it is done by swift :(

Comment: Right @dan, I see. Still strange. I can see levels contain some versioning. Just updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

You will get run time error on device with iOS < 8 on board.
This error will sounds like `unrecognized selector sent to instance`.

You can make a check on object if it can handle your selector like this:

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:selector])
    [self performSelector:selector];
```

or by checking iOS version installed on your device.

Comment: Using this, how can I not put in the "traitCollectionDidChange" method in code.